# Fast array inner access in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I have some lines of code below:

```
wire [WIDTH_PIXEL-1:0] x_vector [0:36];
wire [6-1:0] x_sample [0:511]; // 0 <= x_sample <= 36
reg [WIDTH_PIXEL-1:0] rx_512 [0:511];

genvar p;
generate
for(p=0;p<=511;p=p+1) begin: PPP
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(x_sample[p] == counter2) begin
        rx_512[p] <= x_vector[x_sample[p]]; 
    end
end
```

I want to save 512 x_vector elements whose address is the value of x_sample[p]. The problem is when I synthesize on Quartus, the total LC-combinationals over 50000. I know the problem lies on the line

```
rx_512[p] <= x_vector[x_sample[p]];
```

So is there any way for improving the access memory? Thank you.

Comment: It'd be better to make one `rx_512[p] <= x_vector[x_sample[p]];` assignment per clock cycle. This way your whole operation would take 512 clock cycles, but `rx_512` could be easily implemented as a RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Verilog is meant as a hardware emulation language.
This makes that you have to learn to write two different types of code:

- Code that gets converted to hardware
- Test bench code

For the former there are a lot more restrictions. As you correctly noticed you get 512 comparators each comparing 6 bits plus each conditionally selecting one of 37 PIXELWIDTH values and assigning it to one of 512 PIXELWIDTH destinations. My guess is easily a million gates.

You have to use a divide an conquer approach. As Qiu says make the code sequential: One operation per clock cycle. It will take more clock cycles but a lot less logic. Unfortunately you might find out that you do not have enough time to e.g. process a whole image in that (frame?) time. Then choose to do two or four operations per cycle.
You have to continuously weigh speed versus number of gates & power. Maybe you find out that you can't do the operations at all with the chosen hardware. (Nobody said writing Verilog was easy!)

I don't know if it helps but you can make the compiler/optimizer's life a bit easier if you use:

```
rx_512[p] <= x_vector[counter2];
```

Comment: thank you for your sincere answer. The problem is x_vector will get a new column value in each clock cycle, so I can't delay to 512 clocks to just read 1 column value of x_vector. I think I have to find a new way.